# Is it possible for my upstream router to cache DNS response even I specify a nameserver (e.g. 8.8.8.8)?

Tags: networking, dns

Sometimes the default DNS provided by my IPS couldn't resolve some common sites like discord.com and twitter.com. I change my nameserver to `8.8.8.8`, but it still gets problems from time to time. I wonder if it's possible that my upstream router cached the DNS response? Or when I specify `8.8.8.8` as my nameserver, it will always actually send a query to `8.8.8.8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you no longer use your router's nameservers so do not communicate with them. Your router simply forwards your packets to the nameservers. It always sends a query to `8.8.8.8`.